# swapExactTokensForTokens transaction has different ratio than router interface transaction

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm writing a decentralized buy/sell program and I've stumbled on an issue that I find hard to figure out.

I'm using swapExactTokensForTokens() to swap [this](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x3f6b3595ecf70735d3f48d69b09c4e4506db3f47) token for [WMATIC](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270) on [QuickSwap](https://quickswap.exchange/#/swap).
The ratio is all wrong (121 tokens = 121$ for 0.58 WMATIC = 1.3$).

If I'm using the QS interface I can swap 121 tokens for 43 WMATIC (passing through ETH, so not a direct swap).

My questions are:

- why is the big discrepancy when using a middle pair? how can I prevent this from happening?
- how can I find using the web3 api if my pair is a direct pair or not?

Answer (score 1):

> why is the big discrepancy when using a middle pair? how can I prevent this from happening?

Because a different route is being followed. When there is a middle pair you swap token_a -> token_b then token_b -> token_c. The swap from b -> c gives you a better ratio than a -> c because there are differing amounts in each pool. QS automatically searches all pairs and gives you the best swap rate and constructs the optimal multi-hop swap route. (121:43 MATIC vs 121:0.58 MATIC).

> how can I find using the web3 api if my pair is a direct pair or not?

There is no way. All pairs are inherently "direct" (there are only 2 tokens in a pool). It's up to you to construct a multi-hop route.

Comment: Can I find out from polygonscan the path the transaction took?
Also, what is the logic befind the pair finding? 
I am exchanging a pair of 2 tokens (TOKEN/WMATIC). Why it would take one route over the other? How does quickswap compute the cheapest route? Does it check at least 4 routes (ETC, USDT, USDC, WMATIC) to get that info?

Comment: "Can I find out from polygonscan the path the transaction took?" yes it will show it as multiple swaps. "Why it would take one route over the other?" it will pick the route that gives you the best swap rate. "How does quickswap compute the cheapest route?" This part tends to be proprietary - they likely search thousands of pairs and construct the cheapest route. Sometimes the cheapest route is just a single swap - other times it can involve up to 5+ swaps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. do you have a suggestion for a code that I can look for multiple route finding?

Comment: If you check [this image](https://imgur.com/a/YlZx9OH) the token seems to use a direct pool: GAMER/WMATIC with a very bad exchange rate. It doesn't show a multihop path...